# Designing a circular "selector" control

Tags: ios, user-interface

I'm developing an app that calculates poker odds, and now I'm facing some problems with the card selector.
This is a mockup of what I want.

[image: card selector mockup]

I've found two ways to accomplish this. The first one is to use an entire `UIImageView` and detect touches, calculate where the touch has been generated, and set the corresponding value.
The second one is to use a lot of `UIButton`s, but in this case I get problems with the shape of the buttons.

Of course I can use a regular `UIPickerView` and so on but I think that the one I've designed is better.

Comment: There's a great tutorial by Jeff LaMarche on irregularly-shaped buttons here: http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2010/03/irregularly-shaped-uibuttons.html

Comment: That's great! i've googled a lot but didn't found anything ... thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After googled a little i've found https://github.com/ole/OBShapedButton .
it does anything what i need

Answer (score 0):

if you have a UIButton with a background image that is shaped irregular. then that is the only point that the button can be pressed.

Change the type to custom and put your slices into buttons.

This has been my experience anyhow.

My buttons have to have a .01 alpha background to increase their pad size and people can push the button.

Hope that helps :)

Comment: png with transparencies for the spaces you dont want to touch is the only trick. And setting the button style to custom.

Comment: well , i've already tried to use custom buttons with an custom shaped image but what i get is that the touch area is the green in this image http://dl.dropbox.com/u/8188649/not_ok.png .original image is a 24 bit png with alpha :/

Comment: Well with our app going the way of custom buttons. I am going to have to test this out. I am installing photoshop today so I will see if it is not working. and if not then in the next few days you will likely have an ally in this search..

Comment: i've found this.. i've tested and it's perfect for my needs . https://github.com/ole/OBShapedButton